# Why creating an NUnit project into my solution it use an old version of .NET framework (2.1)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I am pretty new in **C#** and **.NET** and I have the following problem.

I created a **NUnit** (version **3.10.1**) project in my solution. The thing that I can't understand is: why the framework version is the **2.1**? Is not a very old version? If I try to change it I obtain older version, I am attaching a screenshot:

[image]

The strange thing is that the other project into my solution uses the **.NET 4.5.2** framnework version.

Why this NUnit project is using an old framework version? there is a way to update it?

What is wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are targetting .NET Core, which is a completely different framework than the Full .NET Framework.

When you create a new project, you specify the framework to target. You created this one to target .NET Core.

**To change your project to target Full framework 4.5.2:**

- Right click the csproj and select `edit <yourprojectname>.csproj`
- Locate the `<TargetFramework>` element
- Change it from `netcoreapp2.1` to `net452`
- Close the `csproj` file

For more info on .NET Core, you should have a look at the [About .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/about) documentation.

> .NET Core is an open-source, general-purpose development platform maintained by Microsoft and the .NET community on GitHub. It's cross-platform (supporting Windows, macOS, and Linux) and can be used to build device, cloud, and IoT applications.

And taken from the [.NET Core on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core)

[image: Core vs Full framework]

Comment: Ok, I am very unexperienced in .NET. So there is the possibility to change the .NET Core with .NET framework in NUnit project?